# How do I reuse a TCP endpoint address with .Net sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have some client-server socket code that I want to be able to construct and (re)connect to periodically the same endpoint address: `localhost:17999`

Here is the server:

```
// Listen for a connection:
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 17999);             
Socket listener = new Socket(IPAddress.Loopback.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
listener.Listen(1);

// Accept the connection and send a message:
Socket handler = listener.Accept();
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("The Message...");                 
handler.Send(bytes);

// Clean up
handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
handler.Close();
handler.Dispose();

listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
listener.Close();
listener.Dispose();
```

And here is the client:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
Socket receiver = new Socket(IPAddress.Loopback.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
receiver.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
receiver.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 17999));

int num_bytes_received = receiver.Receive(bytes);
string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, num_bytes_received);

receiver.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
receiver.Close();
receiver.Dispose();
```

When I create the client and server for the first time, it works fine. However when I create it again, I get an error:

> "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is
>   not conne cted and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto
>   call) no address was supplied"

I would like to be able to spin up this mechanism arbitrarily whenever I need to with the following order of events:

1. Launch the server and wait to accept a connection
2. Launch the client and connect to the server
3. Accept the client connection at the server
4. Send a message to the client
5. Repeat when necessary

How can I do this?

Thx in Advance!

**EDIT:** Each time I build the client and server objects it is from a different process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what Gene suggested and it seems to work:

```
// Listen for a connection:     
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 17999);
using (Socket listener = new Socket(IPAddress.Loopback.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{

    listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
    listener.Listen(1);

    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        // Accept the connection and send a message:
        using (Socket handler = listener.Accept())
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("The Message...");
            handler.Send(bytes);
        }
    });
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
}
```

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues:

1) You're closing the listener. Just leave it open.

2) You're setting `ReuseAddress` on the wrong socket and way too late. Set it on the listening socket *before* you call `bind` (since that's when you use the address).

Setting `ReuseAddress` on a socket you aren't going to `bind` doesn't do anything. You can remove that from the client.

Comment: (1) Each listener lives in a different process so I should clean up if another process is going to try to make a connection on the same endpoint address, and (2) Tried that but it doesn't make any difference (edited above)

Comment: Does the client or the server get the error message? And when precisely does it happen? (And make sure you start up the server before the client or this is expected behavior.)

Comment: The listener should just accept incoming connections and spawn a new thread handling the client. You often see a `while (Running) { var socket = listener.Accept(); // ... }` in such programs.

Comment: @David, the error occurs in the server at listener.Accept(); the second time I run the client to connect to the same endpoint address

Comment: @Gene, how would this overcome the problem?

Comment: @PatMustard: So, to confirm: 1) You run the server. 2) You run the client, it works. 3) Both the client and server processes terminate. 4) You run the server. 5) You run the client. 6) You get an error in the server. Is that correct?

Comment: Your code looks okay then. Most likely, the problem is in something you haven't told us. Double check that all 6 steps are occurring exactly as you think they are.

Comment: this line `listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);` made the big difference/it possible